S3 Hosted Next.js app returns 404 not found when navigating to specific dynamic route
I have a page on my Next.js app with a path name like: "/slug/:slugId/detailed-view". For some reason when slugId is ab-123, next re-directs me to "/" (but the URL still says"/slug/:slugId/detailed-view"). For any other slugId, such as ab-456, this doesn't happen and it displays the page "/slug/ab-456/detailed-view" correctly. This also doesn't happen locally, only in my deployed environment.
I'm using client side rendering and hosting the app statically on S3.
Here's some of my (simplified) code:
app.jsx:
"use client";

import "../../globals.css";
import RootLayout from "@components/layouts/RootLayout";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => <RootLayout>{page}</RootLayout>);

    return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />);
}

pages/slug/[slugId]/detailed-view.jsx
import LoggedInLayout from "@/app/components/layouts/LoggedInLayout";
import { SlugTemplate } from "@/app/components/templates/SlugTemplate";

const DetailedViewPage = () => {
    return (
            <SlugTemplate type="view" />
    );
}

DetailedViewPage.getLayout = (page) => <LoggedInLayout>{page}</LoggedInLayout>

export default DetailedViewPage;

components/layouts/LoggedInLayout.jsx
const LoggedInLayout = ({ children }) => {

        const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
            // API calls 
    }, [router.asPath]);

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col w-full max-w-[1400px] mx-auto">
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}

export default LoggedInLayout;

components/templates/SlugTemplate.jsx
export const SlugTemplate = ({ type }) => {
        const router = useRouter();

        const [slugId , setSlugId] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (router.isReady) {
            const { slugId } = router.query;
            setSlugId(slugId);
        }
    }, [router.isReady]);

        useEffect(() => {
        // Calls endpoints to fetch data using slugId
    }, [slugId]);
 
        return (
                // Displays data returned by APIs
        );
}

export default SlugTemplate;

next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: "export",
    images: {
        unoptimized: true,
    },
    distDir: "build",
    assetPrefix: "",
}

module.exports = nextConfig

My S3 Static Website Hosting configuration looks like:

Static Website Hosting - Enabled
Hosting Type - Host a Static Website
Index Document - index.html
Error Document - index.html
Redirection Rules - empty

I've tried adding more useEffect()'s with console.log()'s to find the source of the issue, but they never get executed and my console only shows "GET https://my_domain.com/slug/ab-123/detailed-view 404 (Not Found)" and "Navigated to https://my_domain.com/slug/ab-123/detailed-view".
